# Edit document name option in pop up

Tags: usability, gui-design, user-behavior, usability-testing, guidelines

On my UI, when user clicks to create a new document, a pop up opens where a wizard is launched where user must select a folder in which he wants to create the new document. Pop up has a list of all currently present folders. User can select a folder and the click ‘Create Document’ button. This pop up is shown in the image below:

[image]

Now I want to add another feature in my UI i.e.: as user clicks to create a new document first the autgenerated name for the document is shown in an edit box and user can either add a different name or can continue with the autogenerated name since user will not be able to rename this document after this step.

Now here how can I add option for adding document name? Should header for this pop up should also be revised? Or should I add a top bar on this pop up with document name in edit mode unless user moves to next step?

Answer (score 1):

Normally the folder navigation / selection and naming of a document are presented on the *same screen*. Something like this layout:

[image]

The default file name is pre-populated in an editable text field that the user can edit if they wish, or leave as is.